# nginx php5-fpm loading old php.ini file

Tags: nginx, php

I have a PHP-based site running off the usual Nginx and php5-fpm combination. The sites-available config has a few different server blocks in it, e.g. one for the main www.mysite.com and one for blog.mysite.com subdomain. Originally, when I first created the site, I set the `auto_prepend_file` PHP value in my php.ini (in /etc/php5/fpm/), to let's call it 'common.php'. However, I now don't want common.php included for the blog subdomain, so I removed auto_prepend_file from php.ini and added it to the sites-available for the www subdomain, via

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/var/www/mysite/app/lib/common.lib.php";
```

Nothing too fancy there. However, despite restarting both nginx and php5-fpm, I can still sometimes see common.php being included, generally after you've restarted nginx & php5-fpm, reloaded the page, then reload again, i.e. it's fine on the first reload.

When I do a phpinfo() when the file is included, I can see that PHP has loaded the correct php.ini file (i.e. the one I removed the `auto_prepend_file` from), but the `auto_prepend_file` value is still set to common.php!

Is there anything else I need to restart? Should I be looking for `auto_prepend_file` somewhere other than /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini? Thanks

Comment: Probably have better luck asking this on [www.serverfault.com](http://www.serverfault.com)

Comment: thanks @ProfessionalAmateur. Thought this might not be the best place for it alright, but seeing as there are other nginx questions on stackoverflow, I thought I may as well try here. If I get a solution elsewhere, I'll post it here.